# How to fix powershell after installing VS Code

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I already was asking a similar question here: https://superuser.com/questions/1613630/most-of-powershell-commands-not-working?noredirect=1
Basically, I wasn't able to fix the issue so I got a replacement computer. Brand new. Started setting it up and only did the following:

- Installed VS Code
- Turned on Powershell extension in VS Code
- It prompted something about Package Manager needing an update or it will not work properly
- Asked me to install NuGet to get the Package Manager
- After that PowerShell 5.1 stopped working again.

Modules not autoloading, fresh instance of powershell does this:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Write-Host
Write-Host : The term 'Write-Host' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify 
that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Write-Host
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Write-Host:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess your "new"/"replacement" computer is a computer in an enterprise environment with all kinds of custom policies. In that case it is probably looking for a needle in a haystack. You might find a hint in the event viewer, otherwise you will probably need to start with a standard image and include/exclude each custom policy from the issue.

Comment: That's probably what I will have to do. Takes a week to get a new computer, so was hoping to find that needle.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me:

```
(Get-Module -ListAvailable).Name | %{Import-Module -Name $_ -Force}
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol=[Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Install-Module -Name PackageManagement -Force -RequiredVersion 1.4.6 -Scope AllUsers -AllowClobber -Verbose
```

Then if the last command doesn't install NuGet do this:

```
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
```